# Python Decorator accessing self

Tags: python, python-decorators

Here's an example method that's inside a Python Class:

```
def publish_aggregate_account_group_stats(self, account_group_token):
    message = {
        "type": "metrics-aggregate-account-group-stats",
        "accountGroupToken": account_group_token
    }
    try:
        self._get_writer().write(message)
    except:
        self._put_cache(message)
```

There is a handful of methods in my class that all run the `try/except`, that I *think* could be DRYed up or cleaned up by simply creating a decorator that handles that for me. I'm just unsure how the decorator would look/work by accessing `self`.

Answer (score 1):

something like this will work:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.j = set()

    @contextmanager
    def handle_exc(self, msg):
        try:
            yield
        except:
            print('adding to internal structure:', msg)
            self.j.add(msg)

    def test(self):
        m = 'snth'
        with self.handle_exc(m):
            raise Exception('error')
```

a decorator is tough to use here because you're creating values within the function itself, so the outside decorator will never know about them unless you find a way to propagate them up (via a certain exception or something.)